how to read nested xml in penthaho using xml input or xml stream reader?
'I want to read following nested xml in penthaho 5.1.0, in below format, can any one help how to read nested xml in penthaho using xml input or xml stream reader?
input xml -
enter image description here
--- output
can anyone help me for the following output in penthho 5.1.0
enter image description here
mainItemid   name         value
1          Sub Item 1   100
1          Sub Item 2       200
2          Sub Item 3   300
2          Sub Item 4       400'
